# Calcular distancia entre dos coordenadas android

Tags: android

quisiera saber como puedo hallar la distancia entre 2 coordenadas en kilómetros en trayecto vía automóvil, estoy usando la API de google maps.
Agradezco cualquier aporte.

Answer (score 2):

### Usando función distanceTo de GoogleMaps

Googlemaps dispone de la función `distanceTo` documentación oficial de [Location](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html)

**Ejemplo:**

```
Location locationA = new Location("punto A");

locationA.setLatitude(latA);
locationA.setLongitude(lngA);

Location locationB = new Location("punto B");

locationB.setLatitude(latB);
locationB.setLongitude(lngB);

float distance = locationA.distanceTo(locationB);
```

El valor devuelto es en metros.

### Usando CalculationByDistance

O bien puedes probar esa función, extraída de la respuesta [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14394366/find-distance-between-two-points-on-map-using-google-map-api-v2)

```
public double CalculationByDistance(LatLng StartP, LatLng EndP) {
        int Radius = 6371;// radio de la tierra en  kilómetros
        double lat1 = StartP.latitude;
        double lat2 = EndP.latitude;
        double lon1 = StartP.longitude;
        double lon2 = EndP.longitude;
        double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2 - lat1);
        double dLon = Math.toRadians(lon2 - lon1);
        double a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2)
                + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1))
                * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) * Math.sin(dLon / 2)
                * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
        double c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));
        double valueResult = Radius * c;
        double km = valueResult / 1;
        DecimalFormat newFormat = new DecimalFormat("####");
        int kmInDec = Integer.valueOf(newFormat.format(km));
        double meter = valueResult % 1000;
        int meterInDec = Integer.valueOf(newFormat.format(meter));
        Log.i("Radius Value", "" + valueResult + "   KM  " + kmInDec
                + " Meter   " + meterInDec);

        return Radius * c;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo usar la clase Location de android, ya tiene implementado un método para eso

```
Location location = new Location("localizacion 1");
location.setLatitude(0.00000);  //latitud
location.setLongitude(0.00000); //longitud 
Location location2 = new Location("localizacion 2");
location2.setLatitude(0.00000);  //latitud
location2.setLongitude(0.00000); //longitud 
double distance = location.distanceTo(location2);
```

Comment: Gracias, bastante útil.